# Python rotate view on any given angle x , y , or z axis

Tags: python

Using bpy.context.screen.areas you can get the current view or set the view in  TOP or 1 of the other pre set views like LEFT or BOTTOM

How can i change the view to any given angle in Python?

For example 
I would like to rotate the view 45 degrees X axis and 0 for Y and 0 for Z
or i would like to see 45 degrees on all 3 axis

in API i was unable to find any that suggest user input to rotate the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use rotation matrix**

Similarly to object rotation to rotate the view from its current rotation 45 degrees about x axis

*Using code from a previous answer*

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from mathutils import Matrix
context = bpy.context

R = Matrix.Rotation(radians(45), 4, 'X')


for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        space = area.spaces.active
        v3d = space.region_3d   
        v3d.view_matrix = R @ v3d.view_matrix
        v3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'
        break
```

To set it to this rotation instead of transforming by set the view rotation (`Quaternion`)

```
        v3d.view_rotation = R.to_quaternion()
```

To set it to an `Euler`

```
from mathutils import Euler
q = Euler((radians(45), radians(45), radians(45)), 'XYZ').to_quaternion()
v3d.view_rotation = q
```

Comment: What do you want me to say? just what i needed (after little tweek I got the result im after) Thanks @batFINGER